# socket.io reconnect socket.socket.connect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

sorry for posting this issue again, but most of the posts related don't answer my question.
i'm having issues to use multiple connections with the socket.io
i don't get the "socket.socket.connect" method to work, yet i get feedbacks from the first connection.

Here's my structure:

```
var iosocket = null;
var firstconnection = true;
var ip = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx"
var ipPort = 8081

function callSocket() {
    iosocket = null;
    iosocket = io.connect(ip,{port:ipPort,rememberTransport:true, timeout:1500});               

    if (firstconnection) {
    firstconnection= false;                     
    iosocket = io.connect(ip,{port:ipPort,rememberTransport:true, timeout:1500});   
            iosocket.on('connect', function () {console.log("hello socket");}); 
            iosocket.on('message', function(message) {});//end of message io.socket     
            iosocket.on('disconnect', function () {console.log("disconnected");});
    } else {                
     if (iosocket.connected === true) {
        console.log("heyhey still connected");
        iosocket.disconnect();
     }     
     iosocket.socket.connect(ip,{port:ipPort,rememberTransport:true,timeout:1500});
    }  
};
```

it simply doesn't get any feedback from the second connection

Comment: Is this your client code or your server code?

Comment: In what condition you expect that ELSE part of code should execute ?

Comment: this part of the script is on the server-side.  @Blubberguy22

Comment: Else is supposed to check the first connection, i have two games that need to different connections.

Comment: i'm considering changing the code logic, and open a single connection. to manage both games, but i would like to know why i got stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i simply solved that IE8 bug by adding

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of the html

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why this isn't working. For server-side code, this doesn't seem correct for socket.io. The `connect` method is used for clients and not servers. I think you are trying to make the server listen on a port. In that case, you should do:

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = socket.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('someEvent', function(someVariables){
        //Do something with someVariables when the client emits 'someEvent'
        io.emit('anEventToClients', someData);
    });
    client.on('anotherEvent', function(someMoreVariables){
        //Do more things with someMoreVariables when the client emits 'anotherEvent'
        io.emit('anotherEventToClients', someMoreData);
    });
});

server.listen(8000);
```